# How to pass date-picler tag to input type hidden?

Tags: html, vue.js

I am using the date from [address](https://talkhabi.github.io/vue-persian-datetime-picker/guide/)

I want to pass from `date-picker` to `hidden input`.

```
<date-picker type="date" id="inputDate" name="inputDate" format="jYYYY-jMM-jDD" v-model="date"></date-picker>
```

My VUE version is `v2.6.14`.

```
<input type="text" name="inputDate" id="inputDate">
```

script

```
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            dates: [],
            date: '',
        },
        watch: {
            date(newDate) {
                    .then(response => {
                        const inputDate = document.getElementById('inputDate');
                        inputDate.value = newDate;
                    })
            }
        },
        components: {
            DatePicker: VuePersianDatetimePicker
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a watcher or any DOM manipulation to do this.  The power of Vue is being able to 1-way or 2-way bind data variables to input elements. See the official Vue documentation on [Form Input Bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html), it's very helpful to understand.  If the date-picker value is bound to the `date` variable, you can bind `date` to your other input as well.

```html
<input type="text" name="inputDate" id="inputDate" :value="date" />
```

Using `:value` creates a 1-way binding. This makes it so the `<input>` will always reflect the latest value of `<date-picker>` but not vice versa.

[working sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-sound-70ljdc?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: I added this code, but my problem did not solve yet.

Comment: If you add more information about what exactly you tried and what happened then I can try providing more help.  Does the sandbox example at least meet your expected behavior?  I'm not sure what else you need